# How to make MySQL() NOW() function use client's timezone?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I am using the `NOW()` function to store date and time, but the server timezone ( which is my own ) will obviously not work for the whole world.

What I want is for `now()` always to use the CLIENT timezone, whichever it may be.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOW()` executes on current execution timezone (DB Server Timezone). You can use [`CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function along with `NOW()` to get a different timezone representation like

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'GMT','EST');
```

Either way, unless you determine the TZ info of client; at DB end, your DB server has no way determining that.

Comment: But I do not know what someone's timezone might be.

Comment: You can get that information in your app code and pass the same to this function.

Comment: I really cannot ask people for their TZ in the app. And if you meant use JS, then I might as well just get the date from that, but I didn't wanna depend on the user's computer.

Comment: either way, unless you determine the TZ info of client; at DB end, your DB server has no way determining that.

Comment: Your previous comment is the answer I was looking for. Add it to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm, OK. included that in answer.